# Xamarin.Forms Syncfusion PDF DataTable not showing Cyrillic characters

Tags: c#, pdf, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I'm working on Xamarin.Forms App for generating PDF file who can support Cyrillic characters with help of Syncfusion PDF library. This is part of my code example:

```
PdfGrid pdfGrid = new PdfGrid();
Stream f =typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyApp.ArialUnicodeMS.ttf");
PdfFont font = new PdfTrueTypeFont(f, 124);
//PdfFont font = new PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.TimesRoman, 20);
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
page.Graphics.DrawString("ТЕСТ", font, PdfBrushes.Black, new Syncfusion.Drawing.Point(0, 0));
//Include columns to the DataTable
dataTable.Columns.Add("ТЕСТ1");
dataTable.Columns.Add("ТЕСТ2");
dataTable.Columns.Add("ТЕСТ3");
dataTable.Columns.Add("TEST4");
```

Im testing with drawing `String` and drawing `PdfGrid` with `DataTable`

When drawing string it's showing `ТЕСТ` and support cyrillic, but when i add cyrillic characters in DataTable Columns for ex. `ТЕСТ1` show empty string.
Anyone had a similar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have checked the provided code snippet on our end, the  We have to set the supported fonts to dfGrid styles to rendering the Cyrillic characters inside the grid cells. Please try the above code snippet on your end and let us know if it suits your requirement,

```
//Create a PdfGrid.
PdfGrid pdfGrid = new PdfGrid();

Stream f = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyApp.ArialUnicodeMS.ttf");
PdfFont font = new PdfTrueTypeFont(f, 124);

DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
page.Graphics.DrawString("ТЕСТ", font, PdfBrushes.Black, new Syncfusion.Drawing.Point(0, 0));

//Include columns to the DataTable
dataTable.Columns.Add("ТЕСТ1");
dataTable.Columns.Add("ТЕСТ2");
dataTable.Columns.Add("ТЕСТ3");
dataTable.Columns.Add("TEST4");

//Assign data source.
pdfGrid.DataSource = dataTable;

//Set the font to pdfgrid style
pdfGrid.Style.Font = font;
```

Please refer the below link for more information,

UG: https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-tables

**Note**: I work for Syncfusion.